# How to run two separate bash commands at the same time, not in the same line but together Parallelly

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a command x that I want to run alongside command y.

Case in point,
play this song and while this song is playing countdown from five to zero.

I am making `notify-send` command that's counting down from 5 to 0 and while this is happening I want the audio to play which is little alert tone.

I tried doing this
`play ~/xyz && notify-send "somestuff"` and `notify-send "somestuff" && play ~/something` but one doesn't start until the other finished.

So how do I go about this problem?

Comment: @Jetchisel this ```play /notification.wav & notify-send "somestuff"``` is what you mean right? It worked! Thanks a lot! But what do you mean by ```&``` and ```&&``` ? You want me to use ```&&``` as well? Or did you mean to say ```&``` 'instead' of ```&&``` Sorry I am a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry only one `&`,

Comment: OK, yea that is exactly what I wanted! thanks man. This question was marked duplicate and then associated with another question that doesn't even answer my question so I can't mark it as solved but still, this one works.